# Node/Express not responding to POST

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, express

I have an AngularJS front-end talking to a Node/Express/MySQL backend, and all requests work fine apart from a POST request, here's my Angular Code:

```
var Data = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/data_user');
var newData = new Data({'data_id': data_id});
newData.test = 'whatever';
newData.$save(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And I've taken my usual debugging steps of removing all code until something works, however even this is not working (from client):

```
app.post('/api/:table', function (req, res) {
  res.send(200);
});
```

I previously had a MySQL update statement in there, which was being executed properly (with error checking etc), however the front-end is just waiting for a response to come:

(Chrome Dev tools):
data_user
/api
POST
(pending)
Pending

The annoying thing about this is that a CURL works fine:

```
$ curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/data_user --data '{}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 2
Date: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 09:54:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Has anyone got any ideas at all? Can post more code if required

Comment: did your javascript has a missing colon too in `var Data = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/data_user);`

Comment: No, that's my fault copying and pasting, I access tables programmatically in the app like:
        
    var Data = $resource('http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/data_' + table);

But I have no JS errors in either front-end or back-end.

Comment: so I assumed in your devtool you see there is POST to `http://127.0.0.1:9001/api/data_user`. May be you can add wildcard `app.post('*')` to catch all request and print some useful trace.

Comment: So I know I'm hitting the /api/:table call since using a breakpoint, I'm echo-ing out the req and resp objects, but they look fine - I can add status codes etc and of course CURLing the same object is fine.

Comment: Perhaps try `res.json()` instead of `res.send()`?  Perhaps angular is being picky about what it accepts in terms of html headers?  Either that or set the content type in node...? http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#res.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you viewing your page as 127.0.0.1 or as localhost? You may be running into CORS [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). This would explain why a cURL works but a POST request from your page does not work if you are viewing your page as "localhost" but are posting to 127.0.0.1

Comment: It was, inevitably, CORS. I should have mentioned I was running two servers on two ports, but I didn't want to mention damn CORS because I thought I had properly accounted for it (in 14 different places in code). Turns out I was wrong. It's never the code right? Always the programmer... Fixed now, thanks!